# Removing Workflow from the list using SP Object Model in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-object-model

I am interested in removing a Workflow from the list using the SP Object Model. How can I do this?

I am not having much luck with Google today!

Comment: Well, you can work backwards from http://get-spscripts.com/2010/08/add-workflow-to-sharepoint-list-in-all.html the interesting API phrase is [SPList.WorkflowAssociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.workflowassociations.aspx) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So here is the function I wrote that removes the Workflow from the list. Hope it helps someone :)

---

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes the workflow.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="workflowName">Name of the workflow.</param>
/// <param name="spList">The sp list.</param>
private static void RemoveWorkflow(string workflowName, SPList spList)
{
    SPWorkflowAssociation spWorkflowAssociation =
        spList.WorkflowAssociations.Cast<SPWorkflowAssociation>()
          .FirstOrDefault(workflowAssociation => workflowAssociation.Name.Equals(workflowName));

    if (spWorkflowAssociation != null)
    {
        spList.WorkflowAssociations.Remove(spWorkflowAssociation.Id);
    }

    spList.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
   using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://localhost/"))
   {
      using(SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
      {
        SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["DocumentLib"];
        SPWorkflowAssociation objWorkflowAssociation = oList.WorkflowAssociations.Cast<SPWorkflowAssociation>().FirstOrDefault(workflowAssociation => workflowAssociation.Name.Equals("Approval Workflow"));
        if (objWorkflowAssociation != null)
        {
            oList.WorkflowAssociations.Remove(objWorkflowAssociation.Id);
        }
        oList.Update();
      }
   }
```

Its working on my end...

Comment: This removes the workflow association(s) but the workflow still shows as inactive workflow in the workflow settings.  How would you completely remove from the site?